# php find id in 2 arrays that don't match

Tags: php, arrays

I need to find an ID of an array that does not exist in the second array then know the ID. So for example eventid would be the same as id, I need to know if id does not exist in the second array but it does exist in the first array.

so 10001 = 10001,   10002 = 10002,   10003 = 10003,   10004 would be in the first array but not the second. How do I get the result of 1004 not being in the second array.

```
foreach($json as $eventinsert){   

$eventid = $eventinsert['objectId'];

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'Id' => $eventinsert['objectId'],
  'summary' => $eventinsert['name'],
  'description' => $eventinsert['name'],
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => $eventinsert['dateStart']
  ),`enter code here`
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => $eventinsert['dateEnd']
  )
));
foreach ($events as $event) {
    $start = $event->start->dateTime;
    $id = $event->id;
    if (empty($start)) {
        $start = $event->start->date;

    }
   //     printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
   //     printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $id);
    }
```

Comment: Is [`array_diff`](https://3v4l.org/J08ra) good enough for you?

Comment: It sounds like you just want the [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function that's been in PHP since v4?

Comment: array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array in <b>/var/www/html/corp/calsync/insert.php</b> on line

Comment: You told us that you have two arrays, however your error message says otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

1 ) episode: *Unique values*

```
$a = [1001,1002,10003,10004];
$b = [1001,1002,10003,1005];
print_r(array_diff($a,$b)); // Array ( [3] => 10004 )
```

2 ) episode: *Not unique values*

```
$a = [1001,1002,10003,10003,10004,1005,1005,1005];
$b = [1001,1002,10004];
print_r(array_diff($a,$b)); // Array ( [2] => 10003 [3] => 10003 [5] => 1005 [6] => 1005 [7] => 1005 )
```

3 ) episode: *Not unique values. But output unique*

```
$a = [1001,1002,10003,10003,10004,1005,1005,1005];
$b = [1001,1002,10004];
print_r(array_unique(array_diff($a,$b))); // Array ( [2] => 10003 [5] => 1005 )
```

Comment: except they apparently _don't_ have two arrays.

Comment: print_r(array_diff($json,$events)); returns - Recoverable fatal error</b>:  Object of class Google\Service\Calendar\Event could not be converted to string in

Comment: print_r(array_diff($eventinsert,$event)); returns - array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array in

Comment: @RyanFitz  Okay, lets be clear. Which variables do you need to compare ($json,$events) or ($eventinsert,$event) ? And what are values and types of these variables ? And where should be your comparing function placed ?

Comment: As far as I see now. Your title and description don't matches your code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
//Create your variables to store the ID's of the two feeds
$ids_1 = array();
$ids_2 = array();

// Populate the arrays
foreach ($json as $item1) {
    $ids_1[] = $item1['objectId'];
 //   var_dump ($ids_1);
}
foreach ($events as $item2) {
    $ids_2[] = $item2->id;
 //   var_dump ($ids_2);
}

// Loop through the first feed, and exclude the items that are the same in the second
foreach($json as $item){
    if (!in_array($item['objectId'], $ids_2)) {
      //  echo $item->id;
    }
}

// Loop through the second feed, and exclude the items that are the same in the first
foreach($events as $item){
    if (!in_array($item->id, $ids_1)) {
        $service->events->delete($calendarId, $item->id);
        echo "Delete" . $item->id;
    }
}
```